# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix when i use custom control

Tags: java, android, xml

I have custom progressbar control and try to use it from my code. 
I do it so

```
<com.my.app.ArcProgress
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   

    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
    android:background="#214193"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:arc_progress="55"
    custom:arc_bottom_text="Some text"/>
```

ArcProgress:

```
package com.my.app;

public class ArcProgress extends View {
    // some code
}
```

And i encounter error "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix"
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by defining the [**XML** **N**ame **S**pace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) like you did with tools.

So it should be:

```
<com.my.app.ArcProgress 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
    android:background="#214193"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:arc_progress="55"
    custom:arc_bottom_text="Some text" />
```